# Add style to asp:Localize

Tags: asp.net

I have the following tag in an `ASPX` file:

```
<asp:Localize ID="Localize2" 
    meta:resourcekey="locSystemTriggeredClipDurationRc1" runat="server" 
    EnableViewState="False" Text="Some text">
    </asp:Localize>
```

I want to be able to make this text grey color and move it to the right a few pixels as so:

```
<asp:Localize ID="Localize2" 
    meta:resourcekey="locSystemTriggeredClipDurationRc1" runat="server" 
    EnableViewState="False" Text="Some text"
    style="padding: 0px 0 0px 70px;color:grey">
    </asp:Localize>
```

However, this doesn't work.  Is there a way to add styles to an `asp:Localize` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Localize` does not generate any markup, so you can't style it directly, but you always can put it inside `span` and style it:

```
<span style="padding: 0px 0 0px 70px;color:grey">
 <asp:Localize ID="Localize2" 
    meta:resourcekey="locSystemTriggeredClipDurationRc1" runat="server" 
    EnableViewState="False" Text="Some text">
 </asp:Localize>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a quote from [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.localize.aspx) with emphasis added by me

> The Localize control inherits from the Literal control and is
>   identical to it in every way. The Localize control is used at design
>   time to distinguish static text that can be localized from other
>   static text. **Although the Label control allows you to apply a style** to
>   the displayed text, **the Localize control does not**. You can
>   programmatically manage the text displayed in the control by setting
>   the Literal.Text property, inherited from the Literal control.

Comment: +1 for good info.  Would have checked it off if there was a solution.

Comment: no problem, I was sure the solution of wrapping it with style-able control/markup is obvious :)